# Get and setter in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

*I find it very difficult to put this question here because I do not think I can offer anything back to this community.* I currently programming an application that, once it's started, asks the user to login. If the data entered by the user match those in the database, then the user is logged in. Then the application fetches the data about the user from the database such as a user ID, name, role.

Now I would like this information to use widely in the application. My current situation:

- Solution

  - Executable (main project)
  - Database.dll (classes etc)

In database.dll I have the follow class:

```
Public Class SessionProfile
Public _gebruikersID As String
Public _gebruikersNaam As String
Public _gebruikersRole As String

Public Property gebruikersID() As String
    Get
        Return _gebruikersID
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _gebruikersID = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property gebruikersNaam() As String
    Get
        Return _gebruikersNaam
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _gebruikersNaam = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property gebruikersRole() As String
    Get
        Return _gebruikersRole
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _gebruikersRole = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

In my main executable I refer to this class as follow: `Dim SessionProfile As New Database.SessionProfile()` and in my login form I use the following code to set the setter:

```
If loginResult = 1 Then
     SessionProfile.gebruikersID = SQLHook.Results("SELECT * FROM tblgebruikers WHERE GebruikersNaam = '" & TextGebruikersNaam.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'", "GebruikersID")
     SessionProfile.gebruikersNaam = SQLHook.Results("SELECT * FROM tblgebruikers WHERE GebruikersNaam = '" & TextGebruikersNaam.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'", "gebruikersNaam")
     SessionProfile.gebruikersRole = SQLHook.Results("SELECT * FROM tblgebruikers WHERE GebruikersNaam = '" & TextGebruikersNaam.Text.Replace("'", "''") & "'", "gebruikersRole")
     DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
Else
     SessionProfile.gebruikersID = ""
     SessionProfile.gebruikersNaam = ""
     SessionProfile.gebruikersRole = ""
     DialogResult = DialogResult.NO
End If
```

Now I go back to my main form and use for example `MsgBox(SessionProfile.GebruikersNaam)` and I get nothing returned.

Is there a reason this theory is not working or did I something wrong? The query's are good because if you dim them as string and msgbox them, it displays the correct text.

Could somebody help me solving my problem?

Comment: You have declared a variable named 'SessionProfile' in you main executable, could you tell me if that variable is passed to the Login form where you set the properties or do you have declared a new (and different) one?

Comment: @Steve In the main executable I have two forms named 'frmMain' and 'frmLogin' and in both forms this code is declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly you are in the following scenario.

In main executable, somewhere you declare a variable (I will change the name to explain better)

```
Dim currProfile As New Database.SessionProfile()
```

this means you have created a variable of type SessionProfile, now you call the frmLogin

```
Dim form1 As new frmLogin()
if DialogResult.OK = form1.ShowDialog() then
    MsgBox(curProfile.GebruikersNaam) ' shows nothing'
```

inside frmLogin you have declared a new (a different one) variable

```
Dim profile As New Database.SessionProfile()
```

this variable is a different one and shares nothing with the variable declared in the main form, setting its properties doesn't means that the other SessionProfile variable sees these changes.
You need to pass the first variable to the frmLogin. Perhaps in the constructor.

```
Dim form1 As new frmLogin(currProfile)
if DialogResult.OK = form1.ShowDialog() then
    MsgBox(curProfile.GebruikersNaam) ' shows the name'
```

and in the frmLogin constructor receive and store the variable passed in

```
Dim profile As SessionProfile = Nothing
Public Sub New(ByVal p As SessionProfile)
    profile = p
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub
```

Now, when you set the properties on the internal (frmLogin) profile variable you are setting the propertie of the same instance used in your main form.
By the way, avoid to call your variables with the same name of your class. It's really confusing

Comment: I understand your code for 80% and tried implementing this in mine code and I get the idea how to 'solve the problem'. Now at `Public Sub New(ByVal p As SessionProfile)` I get the following error _In designer-generated type 'frmLogin' should call InitializeComponent method._ I have no clue what this means? I am so sorry.

Comment: Well, InitializeComponent is a method written for you by the Visual Studio IDE that declare and initialize every TextBox, Button, DataGrid, etc present in your form. When you declare an explicit New constructor you should call this method (I have forgotten to write it in my answer). Please, read [this article](http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/2001/08/27/winforms.html) about Forms constructor, it is a bit lengthy, but covers the basic.

Comment: Thank you Steve. I followed the instructions and read the article you refered (Its a bit lengthy indeed but I get a small idea out of it). Now when I inserted all your code I get the following error in 'frmLogin': `'profile' is already declared as 'Private profile As Database.SessionProfile' in this class.`. I am so sorry that I am such a huge pain in the *** about my code.

Comment: Can't say, but just search your code where is the second declaration of `profile`.

Comment: It was double refered in the code. It is working now. Thank you Steve for all your help. I did learn something today.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code that you've posted which would explain the issue you are facing, so you might want to post the code on your main form and login form so we can take a look to see what is going on.

However, if you have time for a quick code review, I'd suggest scoping your local fields to be private to the class since you are exposing them via public properties. This will help to "protect" the data in the field from outside sources modifying the data without accessing your setters.

So this:

```
Public Class SessionProfile
Public _gebruikersID As String
Public _gebruikersNaam As String
Public _gebruikersRole As String

Public Property gebruikersID() As String
    Get
        Return _gebruikersID
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _gebruikersID = value
    End Set
End Property ...
```

Should really be this:

```
Public Class SessionProfile
'Limit the scope to be private to the class;
private _gebruikersID As String
private _gebruikersNaam As String
private _gebruikersRole As String

Public Property gebruikersID() As String
    Get
        Return _gebruikersID
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _gebruikersID = value
    End Set
End Property ...
```

Second, and perhaps more importantly, you should really use [parameterized sql statements](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) rather than string concatenation from user entered text. I know you're working with an installed app, but it is a good practice to be in nonetheless.

Neither of these suggestions will help with your initial question, so definitely post more details regarding the code on both the forms in question so we can address the issue at hand.

Comment: I am so sorry. I should have provide the question with more code. Since it is some huge lines of code, I post them on Pastebin.
 `SessionProfile: http://pastebin.com/07ZBVrWM` 
 `frmMain: http://pastebin.com/qDkN9HbU` 
 `frmLogin: http://pastebin.com/kRTkyRJF`

Comment: @Ruvvy no problem, it can be difficult to know what code is causing the problem, so choosing which code to post can be tricky ; ). After looking at your code, I think you'll find Steve's answer very helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a peak in the answer from Steve.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database query is too general if it can only return one value at a time. You only need to make one query to get all the data you need:

```
Dim sp As SessionProfile = Nothing

If loginResult = 1 Then
    Dim sqlConnStr = "your sql connection string"

    Dim nResults As Integer = 0
    Using sqlConn = New SqlConnection(sqlConnStr)

        ' N.B. always select only what you need, and always select explicitly
        Dim sql = "SELECT GebruikersID, gebruikersNaam, gebruikersRole FROM tblgebruikers WHERE GebruikersNaam = @Naam"

        Dim sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", TextGebruikersNaam.Text)

        sqlConn.Open()

        Dim rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        While rdr.Read
            sp = New SessionProfile With {.gebruikersID = rdr.GetString(0), _
                                          .gebruikersNaam = rdr.GetString(1), _
                                          .gebruikersRole = rdr.GetString(2)}

            nResults += 1
        End While

    End Using

    If nResults <> 1 Then
        Throw New Exception(String.Format("User {0} is in database more than once.", TextGebruikersNaam.Text))
    End If

    If sp IsNot Nothing Then
        ' sp now contains the session profile
    End If

End If
```

By using an SQL parameter, you eliminate the need for special treatment of characters such an apostrophe - notice how that code does not do .Replace("'", "''").

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My MySQL wrapper class is a small step to a good one. If you like you can recieve a copy to check how horrible I develop such a class.